# How would I create an index to be used in regression?

Tags: r, regression

I have 2 continuous variables, each having values in the range [0, 1]. Each can be categorized as Low ($\le 0.25$), Medium ($0.25 - 0.70$) and High ($\ge 0.7$). I need to create an index using both the variables and use this index in a regression model. The generated index will be as per following truth table:

```
Var1/ Var2    | Low | Medium | High   |
=======================================
Low           | Low | Low    | Low    |
Medium        | Low | Medium | Medium |
High          | Low | Medium | High   |
=======================================
```

Straight forward multiplication of the two variables is not the solution as some values  will yield a Medium output (var1 = 0.75 and var2 = 0.8 for example).

In the model, I would like to use the index expression (rather than the categorical transformation). This will preserve the data variation.

What f(var1, var2) will provide me this index to be used in lm/R?

Help!!!

Comment: So you don't want the index to be categorical i.e. `'Low','Medium','High'` but rather continuous taking into account the above table you created. But you don't know which method to use to create this numerical index? I am asking because it is not very clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a method to create the numerical index. As specified below, using minimum of var1 and var2 will eliminate the variations in var1 or var2. I would like to preserve it and possibly use it in the regression too.

Comment: Can you give an example? What do you like as output if var1 = 0.1 and var2 = 0.2? Or can you explain what you want to regress? Maybe this is not the easiest way to go.

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses. I am in the process of determining impact of liquidity on financial asset prices. Liquidity is ease of trading. Volume and number of trades are 2 most important dimensions of  liquidity. Individually they don't provide the correct picture. Jointly they do. Consider, large trading volume but with few trades means illiquid market. Large volume with large number of trade transactions makes an asset quite liquid. In my case, the 2 variables correspond to  percentage of total volume and number of trades for a given asset in a specified time period.

Comment: I can use them individually in regression to get individual impact but to get clear picture, I would like to assess the joint impact of both of them. One easy approach is to make an numerical index out of both. Hence the question. I welcome other approaches too.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether there is an inbuild function for this and I couldn't find it instantly. Can you use something like the following?

```
get_index <- function(var1, var2)
{
    if (var1 < 0 || var1 > 1 || var2 < 0 || var2 > 1)
        return("out of range");

    low <- min(var1, var2);
    if (low < 0.25)
        return("Low");
    if (low <= 0.70)
        return("Medium");

    return("High");
}
```

Comment: There is an inbuilt function named `interaction`, but it would deliver a disjoint 9 value classification rather than the type of interaction requested.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
cfun <- function(x) cut(x,c(-0.01,0.25,0.7,1.01),
              labels=c("low","medium","high"))
var1c <- cfun(var1)
var2c <- cfun(var2)
comb <- ifelse(var1c=="low" | var2c=="low", "low",
           ifelse(var1c=="medium" | var2c=="medium", "medium",
                "high"))
```

or actually, as suggested by other answers:

```
cfun(min(var1,var2))
```

Comment: Despite the fact that `cut` by default creates right-closed intervals and findInterval by default creates left-closed intervals, in this problem we will get the same results (almost all of the time).

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading your request my (second) guess is that you want this:  only the "numerical index" and you could dispense with the use of a character vector label. If entered as a numerical variable in a regression formula the p-value for that synthetic interaction would give you a "test of trend" for the joint "minimum" descretized level condition.

```
inter.n <-  pmin( findInterval(x, c(0, .25, .7, 1)), 
                  findInterval(y, c(0, .25, .7, 1)) )
```

Earlier comments:
At the moment it is unclear how you want the inequalities to work when values are at the boundaries. The `findInterval` function can be used when the boundaries are closed on either the right (the default) or the left. You say : " Low ($\le 0.25$), Medium ($0.25 - 0.70$) and High ($\ge 0.7$)", which would make a value of either 0.2 or 0.7 a member of two groups. There would be fairly simple code with which is Low ($\lt 0.25$), Medium ($\ge 0.25 & $\lt 0.70$) and High ($\ge 0.7$):

```
  x=runif(1000)
  y=runif(1000)
 inter <- c("Low", "Middle", "High")[ pmin( findInterval(x, c(0,.25,.7,1)), 
                                          findInterval(y, c(0, .25, .7, 1)))]
> table(inter)
inter
  High    Low Middle 
    78    383    539
```

If you use a modification of @BenBolker's `cfun` that makes ordered factors, you can get `pmin` to work directly on the values:

```
cfun2 <- function(x) cut(x,c(0, 0.25, 0.7, 1.01), include.lowest=TRUE, 
               labels=c("low","medium","high"), ordered=TRUE)
inter.f <- pmin( cfun2(x) , cfun2(y) )

 table(inter.f)
#--------
inter.f
   low medium   high 
   449    473     78
```

And that is in some ways superior because the `table` function automagically honors the ordering of the factor labels.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner at R languange and syntax, but it seems you are more looking for a *function* rather than a procedure.

What about using f(var1, var2)=min(var1,var2)? Clearly, you have to apply this to the numeric version, and *then* categorize the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view since you want to use this new index in a regression, you are trying to do what is known as feature elimination. Generally, it is best that you use all the variables that you have if the total number of variables is small. Now if the number of variables is big and you need to therefore eliminate some then there are multiple ways to do it including stepwise elimination, recursive feature elimination etc.

In your case you only have 2 variables and essentially you want to combine those 2 without losing any variance. Well, to my point of view one thing you can use is Principal Component Analysis. Let's see an example:

```
#create data
var1 <- runif(1:100)
var2 <- runif(1:100)
df <- data.frame(var1,var2)

#the below line will create a PCA model
PCAmod <- princomp(var1+var2,data=df) #uses formula syntax without a response variable

> summary(PCAmod)
Importance of components:
                          Comp.1
Standard deviation     0.4052599
Proportion of Variance 1.0000000
Cumulative Proportion  1.0000000
```

The above shows that a new principal component has been created i.e. a vector of 100 new elements that in this example explains 100% of the variance of var1 and var2 (proporsion of variance in the table above).

```
newvar <- PCAmod$scores #the new vector
```

Essentially, the `newvar` can be used instead of var1 and var2

If you need the vector to be numbers ranging between [0,1] then you can scale it:

```
scaled_newvar <- scale(newvar,center=min(newvar), scale=max(newvar)-min(newvar) )

> summary(scaled_newvar)
     Comp.1      
 Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.2991  
 Median :0.4607  
 Mean   :0.4788  
 3rd Qu.:0.6566  
 Max.   :1.0000
```

However, the above will **probably not confirm** your `'low','medium','high'` condition table but I think this is the right thing to do if you will use the above in a regression.

If the above is not satisfying enough then (and I wouldn't recommend it) then:

1. Just use the min(var1,var2) for each combination and use that
2. Multiply the two, applying the boundary value if it is outside the range you would want it to be e.g. if both var1 and var2 are high and their product is medium then choose 0.75 as the correct value.
3. According to your final edit, you could just multiply the 2 together without caring about 'low','medium','high'

Comment: In order to reply to people use @their_name otherwise no one receives a message. Saying this for your message above. I still think PCA is the best choice for this. Let me know of your concerns.

Comment: thanks for the input. I need to incorporate recommended PCA approach in my model. Depending on the output, I will post my findings.